# How can I manage the frames inside a "QMainWindow" widget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, frame

In these days I'm trying to replicate a GUI already written with Tkinter with PyQt5, but I'm new with this framework and I don't still know how to complete some steps. Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
import sys

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        """MainWindow constructor"""
        super().__init__()

        self.title="Main Window"
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height = 250, 250, 760, 620
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.setMinimumSize(760, 620)

        self.CreateMenu()
        self.CreateFrames()

        self.show()

    def CreateMenu(self):
        MainMenu=self.menuBar()
        EditMenu=MainMenu.addMenu("Test1")
        HelpMenu=MainMenu.addMenu("Test2")

        Test1_1=qtw.QAction("Test1-1", self)
        Test1_1.triggered.connect(self.Test)
        EditMenu.addAction(Test1_1)

        Test2_1=qtw.QAction("Test2-1", self)
        Test2_1.triggered.connect(self.Test)
        HelpMenu.addAction(Test2_1)

    def CreateFrames(self):
        TheFrame=qtw.QWidget(self)
        TheFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color:blue")
        self.setCentralWidget(TheFrame)

        TheLayout=qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        TheFrame.setLayout(TheLayout)
        MainFrame, ButtonsFrame = qtw.QFrame(), qtw.QFrame()
        MainFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color:red"), ButtonsFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color:green")
        TheLayout.addWidget(MainFrame)
        TheLayout.addWidget(ButtonsFrame)

        # the "resize" method doesn't work..
        self.Button1=qtw.QPushButton("Button 2")
        self.Button1.resize(50,100)
        self.Button2=qtw.QPushButton("Button 2")
        self.Button2.resize(50,100)
        self.Button3=qtw.QPushButton("Button 2")
        self.Button3.resize(50,100)

        ButtonsLayout=qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        ButtonsFrame.setLayout(ButtonsLayout)
        ButtonsLayout.addWidget(self.Button1)
        ButtonsLayout.addStretch()
        ButtonsLayout.addWidget(self.Button2)
        ButtonsLayout.addWidget(self.Button3)

    def Test(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Inside the main window, I create `TheFrame` (the blu frame), and inside of it, I create the `ButtonsFrame` and `MainFrame` too (the green and the red ones). My questions are:

1. Did I follow the right approach? I mean, does PyQt make me to create `TheFrame`? Because I thought, is it not better to create `ButtonsFrame` and `MainFrame` in the main window directly? I tried but it didn't work.. I can't create a new layout in a `QMainWindow` widget, there is a default one, but I don't know about its nature. What kind of layout is it?
2. When I put the `ButtonsFrame` and `MainFrame` inside `TheFrame`, I realized that exist some default spaces between the widgets (I sign them in the attached screenshot). How can I manage the size of these default spaces manually? I saw the same spaces when I put the buttons widgets..
3. When I use the `QHBoxLayout` object, how can I set a static height for the frames placed inside it? For example, in my code I want to set a default height for the `ButtonsFrame`, in my mind it has not to expand upwards. How can I do it?
4. How can I change the size for my buttons? As you can see, the `resize` method doesn't work..

Attached screendhot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL; DR;** Everything it asks for is in [the Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/). The Qt docs is one of the best since they clearly indicate the limitations and what functionalities they cover, so it is recommended that any Qt user read it.

---

1. If you check [the docs of QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) it clearly indicates that this widget has a predefined structure (check the link for more information as well as this question has been many times in SO).

   [image]

   If you don't want that default structure then use QWidget instead of QMainWindow which is the basic building block for building any type of widget.
2. Those spaces can be modified using the QHBoxLayout's [`setContentsMargins()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) and [`setSpacing()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#spacing-prop) methods.

   ```py
   TheLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 20, 30, 40)
   TheLayout.setSpacing(50)
   ```
3. The layouts are managers of the geometry (position and size) of the child widgets of the parent widget where it is set, so they use additional information (such as sizeHint, sizePolicy, stretch factor, etc). So if you want to set a fixed height then set that height in the container:

   ```py
   ButtonsFrame.setFixedHeight(300)
   ```

   Or in this case it is better to make the top widget stretch as much as possible by setting a factor to 1.

   ```
   TheLayout.addWidget(MainFrame, stretch=1)
   TheLayout.addWidget(ButtonsFrame)
   ```
4. As the geometry of the button is handled by the layout then using resize() will not change anything as the layout will restore it to its default size. To avoid this then it is better to use [`setFixedSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize-1):

   ```py
   self.Button1 = qtw.QPushButton("Button 2")
   self.Button1.setFixedSize(50, 100)
   self.Button2 = qtw.QPushButton("Button 2")
   self.Button2.setFixedSize(50, 100)
   self.Button3 = qtw.QPushButton("Button 2")
   self.Button3.setFixedSize(50, 100)
   ```

Comment: Sorry, I had connection problems and didn't see that you've already answered...

Comment: @musicamante Why are you apologizing? My posting an answer does not imply that you or another member of the community should not answered. On the contrary, this way we give a clearer vision of the solution.

Comment: well, I thought it would be polite, your answer is, as usual, succint and correct, and could be quite enough for what the OP asked... Or I could have saved 10 minutes of typing if my network worked ;-)

Comment: @musicamante hahaha, or vice versa: If you had posted it then I could have saved myself those minutes :-). I love to answer the answers with more challenges, that is, those that were never made, such as integration with other technologies.

Comment: I completely agree... For once we didn't have the usual pyuic edited file issue ;-)

Comment: @musicamante, eyllanesc: thanks for your replies guys, two is better than one ;)

Answer (score 1):

QMainWindow (a very special kind of QWidget, which is the base for all ui elements in Qt) doesn't allow to set your own layout because it has its own *private* layout that is used to manage everything that is commonly created in a "main window". You can see this from the [QMainWindow documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details):

[image: QMainWindow layout]

Since those objects need to be automatically positioned and resized whenever the window (or any of its content) is resized, and since this positioning is quite complex due to the nature of some widgets (dock widgets and toolbars) that layout is internally managed.

This leaves you with the "only" possibility to create "just one" central widget. But that's not a big deal: it's common practice to create an empty QWidget that acts as a *container* in case your UI has more than one "main" widgets, like in your case.

The borders you see around the two internal frames are created by default for any layout, and can be controlled using [`setContentsMargins()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins). You can use [`getContentsMargins()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#getContentsMargins) to get the current default margins for the layout and then change them as you wish. For instance, if you want to avoid only the top border, in case there is one:

```
    left, top, right, bottom = self.getContentsMargins()
    if top:
        self.setContentsMargins(left, 0, right, bottom)
```

Be aware that even QWidget subclasses have content margins (with the same function names), which *could* add additional margins to the widget, other than those set on the layout, but note that those margins are usually only respected by some widgets (normally, containers, like QFrame).

The border you see *between* those frames is controlled by the layout's *spacing* property. For all layouts it can be get (`getSpacing()`) and set (`setSpacing()`) as a global value that is kept for all spacings between elements, but it can also be set individually for vertical or horizontal spacings in the QGridLayout (`setHorizontalSpacing()`, `setVerticalSpacing()`).

Changing the size of widgets is a bit more complex. Layout managers are, indeed, managers for the layout, which means that it's up to them to decide how big elements are and where they should be put, so using `resize()` on a widget managed by a layout is completely pointless.

When a widget is managed by a layout, the layout queries its [`sizePolicy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop), which is an objects that describes how the widget should behave when Qt has to decide its geometry.

Some widgets have one of their size that is fixed (it's the case of the vertical size of buttons, which can only expand horizontally by default), other have an *expanding* policy (meaning that they will try to occupy as much space as possible), while others have a *preferred* size (so they will try to grow if possible, but if in the same layout there's an *expanding* element, that will take precedence).

All of that is then based on the widget's [`sizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop), which is the *preferred* size for the widget in normal condition (and that could return different values depending on the situation and the widget type), and that the layout will use to decide how to set the geometry considering the widget's policy.

That policy can be overridden in various ways:

- by setting a *new* size policy for the widget;
- by getting the size policy of the widget, changing one of its properties, and then setting it back to the widget (changing the size policy alone will not affect the widget, as the size policy is not an object that sends "notifications");
- by setting a minimum or maximum size constraint (using `set(Minimum|Maximum|Fixed)(Width|Height|Size)`);
- adding the widget to the layout *and* setting a *stretch* value, which is an integer value that tells the layout the *proportion* of that element against others; for instance, if you add a button with `addWidget(button1, stretch=1)` and another with `addWidget(button2, stretch=2)`, the second will have twice the size of the first;

Finally, an important consideration.
Qt layouts allow *nesting* of layouts: for instance, you can add an horizontal layout to a vertical one, if you don't like the rows/columns arrangement QGridLayout provides. And then you can add another vertical layout to that horizontal one. This happens because all items added to a layout are in fact [QLayoutItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html#details) objects, which are abstract items used to represent "objects" added to a layout: when a widget is added using `addWidget()`, the layout creates a QLayoutItem for it.
Also note that every QLayout class is, in fact, a QLayoutItem subclass; when you add a spacing to a box layout (or a stretch) you're actually adding a QSpacerItem (again, a QLayoutItem subclass) that has a fixed or expanding size policy.

The subject is quite complex, and I can understand that you might be confused if coming from a slightly simpler framework, so I suggest you to take your time, and carefully read the documentation about the following topics:

- [QWidget size hints and size policies](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-hints-and-size-policies)
- [QSizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html)
- [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)
- [QLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html) and [QLayoutItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html)
- [Using layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)

I also suggest you to do *a lot* of experiments, both from code *and* with Qt Designer, which will allow you to better understand how Qt layout management works.
It's not always intuitive, so be patient and keep always an eye on the documentation.

<sup>A small hint: Designer doesn't allow to set a layout for a *parent* widget if no child widget exists. A common mistake is to create a main window, then add a widget container and set a layout for that container; since Designer creates main windows with a central widget already set (and which cannot be changed), the result is that the created container won't adapt its size to the main window. Just ensure that *`centralwidget`* has a layout (you can see it from its icon in the object inspector). If you want to set a layout for a widget but still need to have it empty (because you want to add child widgets only from code), just add an arbitrary widget to the parent, set the layout, and remove that widget.</sup>